# Numpy indexing 2d array with 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, np.argsort

I am trying to understand how Numpy indexing work.

Take a look at the following code:

```
A = np.array([
    [10, 7, 3, 100],
    [1, 7, 0, 3],
])
B = np.argsort(A, axis=1)

# B = [
#       [2 1 0 3]
#       [2 0 3 1]
#     ]

A[B]
```

Based on pure logic if I first get the sorted indexes of A using `argsort` I should then be able to index A using ITS OWN sorted indexes out of the box without doing any extra work. Instead I get the folliwing error:

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Why is this? Can someone explain how this type of indexing work in Numpy?

Even more strange is the following code:

```
A = np.array([
    [10, 7, 3, 100],
    [1, 7, 0, 3],
])
B = np.argsort(A, axis=1)

# B = [
#       [2 1 0 3]
#       [2 0 3 1]
#     ]

C = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

C[B] # It works
```

The code above works fine.
I thought this was working because of broadcasting:

B: (2, 4)

C: (4,  )

Left alignment of C:

C: (1, 4)

Repetition of C:

C: (4, 4)

But now we are basically back at the first case... So why does this work?

Comment: Also read the [manual for `argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). It shows you how to handle the two-dimensional case correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly obtained the sorted indices of array A along the rows (axis 1) using argsort. So, B is a 2D array containing the sorted indices. However, when you try to use these indices to index array A, numpy interprets them as indexing the rows of A, not the elements within each row.

To achieve what you want, you need to perform advanced indexing on both dimensions of the array. You can achieve this by using the np.indices() function to generate index arrays for both row and column positions, and then use them to index A with B:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [10, 7, 3, 100],
    [1, 7, 0, 3],
])
B = np.argsort(A, axis=1)

# Generate row and column indices
row_indices = np.arange(A.shape[0])[:, None]  # Convert to column vector
C = A[row_indices, B]

print(C)

# output
[[  3   7  10 100]
 [  0   1   3   7]]
```

Comment: Why does indexing C work instead?

Comment: I would suggest to check out this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_advanced_indexing.htm
If it's still not clear, we'll go on.

Comment: Each dimension of `A` needs an indexing array (or slice), and those arrays need to `broadcast` against each other.  `row_indices` is a (2,1) array, `B` is a (2,4).  The result is (2,4) array of values.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is to use [`take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
np.take_along_axis(A, B, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[  3,   7,  10, 100],
       [  0,   1,   3,   7]])
```